# CSS Print Width Not Applying

Tags: css, print-css

I've been trying to simply make my #content div be 100% width in a print stylesheet. No matter what I try, I just can't seem to get this to work.

A screencap of the visual can be seen here: http://t.co/brgvKPtKxA

The header message goes 100% across--which is interesting, but nothing else.

My CSS looks like:

```
@media print {

    html, body, #content { width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block; overflow: visible; padding-right: 30px; }
    @page { size: portrait; margin: 1cm; }
    nav, #search, footer, #breadcrumbs, #pull-search, #scroll-to-top, img, #aside { display: none; }

    h1 { font-size: 22pt; }
    h2 { font-size: 18pt; }
    h3 { font-size: 14pt; }
    p, ul, ol { font: 10pt/13pt Times New Roman, serif; }
    table { page-break-inside : avoid; }

    header:before {
        display: block;
        content: "Thank you for printing our content at www.schoolcraft.edu. Please check back often for news and updates.";
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
        font-style: italic;
        padding: 3px 5px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }

} /* end of print query */
```

My code is a bit messy because I keep trying new things each second. I've ran into this before, but I have never been this stumped. Any suggestions?

Your time and help is appreciated.

Maria

HTML Code Snippet:

```
<section id="content">               
<div class="sf_cols">
    <div class="sf_colsOut sf_2cols_1_75" style="width: 76%; ">
        <div id="MainContent_Content_C004_Col00" class="sf_colsIn sf_2cols_1in_75" style="margin: 0px 70px 0px 0px; ">
            <div class='sfContentBlock'>
                <h1>Heading</h1> 
                <p>Maecenas laoreet bibendum nisi, vitae pharetra dolor. Sed id viverra enim, semper tincidunt magna. Curabitur varius nisl vel sapien commodo, id gravida ipsum elementum. Integer dui orci, malesuada eget hendrerit tempor, interdum vel tortor. Phasellus quis leo aliquet, feugiat turpis sed, egestas libero. Duis placerat hendrerit lacus in vulputate. Aliquam tristique, neque vel vehicula eleifend, urna erat imperdiet orci, id pulvinar tellus nisi in quam. Etiam a varius justo. Quisque consectetur commodo velit ac laoreet. Suspendisse aliquet vehicula urna. Vestibulum at justo non nibh placerat aliquet vel a arcu. Morbi at convallis ante. Vivamus in nulla quis mauris ornare tempus. Nam ultrices nisi quis nisi ullamcorper iaculis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla facilisi.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sf_colsOut sf_2cols_2_25" style="width: 24%; ">
        <div id="MainContent_Content_C004_Col01" class="sf_colsIn sf_2cols_2in_25" style="margin: 0px; ">            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have other css attached to that page?

Comment: I do have @media screen CSS above this section, but even the !important isn't having much influence.

Comment: Ok, what if you remove that padding-right: 30px;

Comment: That didn't do it either. The 30 isn't even applying it seems if I make the numbers extreme. A friend on Twitter noticed a class (.sf_2cols_1_75) with an inline style of 76%. This is generated from the CMS and changes often per page. I'm not sure if I can override this which appears to be the problem.

Comment: can you post the html..? you should just check widths of elements in it with firebug and override those widths in print css.

Comment: Here is the generated HTML code for the #content area I'm trying to adjust: (I added it in my original post)

Comment: I'm pretty much trying to find a way to make each column width 100% so they just stack upon print.

Answer (score 0):

remove these:

```
style="width: 76%;"

style="width: 24%;"
```

and add id:s (id="content_right", id="content_left") for your div:s like this:

```
<section id="content">               
<div class="sf_cols">
    <div id="content_left" class="sf_colsOut sf_2cols_1_75">
        <div id="MainContent_Content_C004_Col00" class="sf_colsIn sf_2cols_1in_75" style="margin: 0px 70px 0px 0px; ">
            <div class='sfContentBlock'>
                <h1>Heading</h1> 
                <p>Maecenas laoreet bibendum nisi, vitae pharetra dolor. Sed id viverra enim, semper tincidunt magna. Curabitur varius nisl vel sapien commodo, id gravida ipsum elementum. Integer dui orci, malesuada eget hendrerit tempor, interdum vel tortor. Phasellus quis leo aliquet, feugiat turpis sed, egestas libero. Duis placerat hendrerit lacus in vulputate. Aliquam tristique, neque vel vehicula eleifend, urna erat imperdiet orci, id pulvinar tellus nisi in quam. Etiam a varius justo. Quisque consectetur commodo velit ac laoreet. Suspendisse aliquet vehicula urna. Vestibulum at justo non nibh placerat aliquet vel a arcu. Morbi at convallis ante. Vivamus in nulla quis mauris ornare tempus. Nam ultrices nisi quis nisi ullamcorper iaculis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla facilisi.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content_right" class="sf_colsOut sf_2cols_2_25">
        <div id="MainContent_Content_C004_Col01" class="sf_colsIn sf_2cols_2in_25" style="margin: 0px; ">            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then add this to your **desktop** css:

```
#content_left {
  width: 76%;
}

#content_right {
  width: 24%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hardy. I'm still looking into this. The problem is that those width attributes are generated from the CMS. It's not hardcoded somewhere for me to simply remove. I totally get that concept though, and this makes sense. The width is definitely causing the issue.

Comment: What CMS you are using?

Comment: We are using Sitefinity CMS